# Is there anything besides sodium to avoid to lower blood pressure?

Tags: sodium, potassium, hypertension

I've been told that sodium can cause hypertension, and that I should eat about twice as much potassium as sodium to lower my blood pressure (along with a calorie restricted diet and regular exercise). I am doing all this, and my blood pressure still is higher than I'd like it.

I'm wondering if there is anything besides sodium that I should avoid, or is sodium the ONLY thing that causes high blood pressure? Searching online for this answer is particularly difficult because there is so much out there saying sodium should be avoided, yet this seems to be the ONLY thing to avoid with respect to hypertension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aging process itself can cause a stiffening of the blood vessels; also our genes, etc. In general, for people with hypertension, more potassium is better. One might use a salt substitute, like "Morton's Salt Substitute", which is potassium chloride. Or drink low sodium v-8 juice, which is high in K. One might also take Magnesium citrate, or Mg-taurate supplements; according to label. One might also take a garlic supplement like Garlicin HC (TM) according to label instructions, or another good garlic supplement (e.g. Kwai).  If one likes celery, this makes a good snack!  And the general advice still applies:  report all supplements you take to your doctor when you visit.

P.S. If a person has pre-existing kidney disease, they should consult a doctor before beginning to supplement  potassium and/or magnesium.

Studies etc. K https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/21403995/

Mg: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/22051430/

Celery:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/25352064/  Also:  https://www.google.com/amp/s/health.clevelandclinic.org/celery-may-help-bring-your-high-blood-pressure-down/amp/ There is a lot more interesting stuff on the web about celery and other than just this. This study addresses the kidneys, high bp  is not good for the kidneys over time.

Garlic:  https://www.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-300/garlic

There is plenty of quality material on the net regarding K, mg, celery and garlic to aid control of hypertension.

NB:  Of course, those with hypertension, even mild hypertension, should be under the care of a doctor and as I said above, the doctor should be informed of the supplements one takes.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].